# rdata: getting a vector of similar values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns: an ID and some numeric value foo. I want to be able to get a vector of the IDs corresponding to foo values similar to the foo value of a given ID. Is there some easy way to do this in R?

Comment: Hi Wells, can you give a minimum working example (MWE)? Even though to you it's obvious what you want, the easiest way to see what you want is to provide an example vector (in your case) and what you want the result to be. Also give your best attempt, if you have one, but that's not as necessary as the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you have a dataframe rather than a vector. Maybe something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, foo = runif(10))
givenID <- 8
tolerance <- 0.2
subset(df, abs(foo - foo[id == givenID]) < tolerance)$id
```

It will include in the output the given ID, but you can get rid of that if you need to, wrap it in a function, etc.

Comment: +1 - but you should remove the unneeded `df$` parts from the `subset` statement.